# how to write exclude constraint with grouped rows postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, constraints

i have some_table (postresql):

```
create table some_table (
    id int primary key,
    s int not null,
    d int not null,
    idx_grp int,
    start_date date not null,
    end_date date nit null
)
```

First tasks was to create unique pair (s, d) on date interval (start_date, end_date). I can solve this problem via constraint

```
EXCLUDE USING gist (s with =, d with =, daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') WITH &&),
```

But now i need use column `idx_grp`. Idea is that column is subgroup of pair (s, d).
If exist pairs (s_x, d_x, g_1) and (s_x, d_x, g_2) on the same date interval its correct.
If g=0 of some pair (s_x, d_x) this means pair (s_x, d_x) belongs all groups. Therefore there cannot be a situation when exist any other row with pair (s_x, d_x) in the table.
Additionally if exist pair (s_x, d_x) with some group (g_x) then you cannot add pair with all groups (s_x, d_x, 0).
How can i update or rewrite my constraint to solve this situation?

Comment: Have you tried creating an operator?

Comment: Can you explain? Which operator?

Comment: What: "*which operator*"? I am asking if you have tried **creating** one. You want 2 values of `idx_grp` to be in conflict if they are equal or either is equal to 0, right? It is not an equal operator (it is reflexive, symmetric but not transitive, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) but it looks similar to the range overlap operator (also reflexive, symmetric and not transitive) and at first glance, is something you could put in a user-defined operator easily and use in your exclusion constraint. If it works for `&&`, it should work for a new operator too, no?

Comment: I actually got interested in the topic too and asked what was needed to have an exclusion constraint work with a user-defined operator. In the process, someone smarter than me has solved your issue. See (and upvote) answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78123007/20143744