# Exclusion constraint with user-defined operator

Tags: postgresql

On Postgres 16, I am trying to see if it is possible to define exclusion constraints with a user-defined operator, to support more cases than the predefined operators allow.

The operator `=?=` checks if 2 values are equal or whether either is 0; it is defined as:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EqualOrZero(a anycompatible, b anycompatible)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
COST 1
IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
AS $body$
BEGIN
    RETURN a = b OR a = 0 OR b = 0;
END;
$body$;

CREATE OPERATOR =?= (
    FUNCTION = EqualOrZero,
    LEFTARG = anycompatible,
    RIGHTARG = anycompatible,
    COMMUTATOR = =?=
);
```

AFAICT, it works, as demonstrated by:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
a INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (0),(1),(2);

SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1
JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.a =?= T2.a
```

However, when trying to use it in an exclusion constraint:

```sql
ALTER OPERATOR FAMILY gist_int4_ops USING GIST
ADD OPERATOR 1 =?= (anycompatible, anycompatible);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
a INTEGER NOT NULL,
EXCLUDE USING GIST (a with =?=)
);

/* Case 1: multiple insert */
/* Next query raises exclusion constraint violation as expected. */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (0),(1),(2);
/* Next query also raises exclusion constraint violation. */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1),(2);

/* Case 2: insert 1 record at a time */
/* OK */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1);
/* Exclusion constraint violation unlike expected */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2);
/* No error unlike expected */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (0);
/* Now, the table contains 0 and 1 */
```

What's more, the below query does not return the correct result (only 1 record is returned although 4 are expected: `0, 0`, `0, 1`, `1, 0`, `1, 1`). I have traced it back to the execution plan showing `Index Only Scan using mytable_a_excl on public.mytable as t2`. I suppose if the exclusion constraint cannot use the operator correctly, the result is bound to be incorrect.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1
JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.a =?= T2.a
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.
For comparison, the range overlap `&&` operator shares some properties with my `=?=` operator and as such, I would expect what works for one should work for the other operator:

- Symmetry (`n =?= n` for all `n`)
- Reflexivity (if `a =?= b`, then `b =?= a`)
- Non-transivity (`a =?= b` and `b =?= c` does not mean `a =?= c`)

How can I make it work?

Comment: Operator 1 in that family already exists, with a more specific signature and different semantics (`<`).  Adding another operator 1 with a different signature and semantics just confuses things, tricking it into accepting situations which it doesn't know how to deal with, like this one.  I think it is actually deploying < to do the checks, which is corrupt because < is not its own commutator.

Comment: It does exist but not for `anycompatible` arguments. Your comment helped me understand that was the reason why I could run that query at all

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a random operator to an existing operator class. You'd have to define your own GiST operator class with all the required support functions; see [the definition of `gist_int4_ops`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=contrib/btree_gist/btree_gist--1.2.sql;h=1efe75304384f27211597e23283a6f369b7edf40;hb=HEAD#l447) in the [btree_gist](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html) extension.

You can get an exclusion constraint that does what you want using ranges:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD CONSTRAINT weird EXCLUDE USING gist (
   int4range(
      nullif(a, 0),
      nullif(a, 0),
      '[]'
   ) WITH &&
);
```

That maps each integer different from 0 to a range that contains only that number, and 0 is mapped to an infinite range that conflicts with everything.

Comment: Nice hack for the table definition I presented, definitely the way to go there. However, how should I proceed in a situation where I could find no alternative expression? Is there a place where I can consult what the support functions are supposed to do, at least to get a sense of how complex it would be to walk that path?

Comment: Studying the `btree_gist` source code is perhaps the best you can do.